# How should I rendering specific values of a collection with backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm brand new to Backbone and am having trouble finding information on how to access specific values from a collection. In this demo, I'm trying to grab the "image_url" value from my collection and put it in the template. I can't figure out how to do that.

HTML

```
<script type="text/template" id="dribble_details">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="<%= image_url %>">
    </a>
  </div>
</script>
```

Model:

```
Shot = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(opts) {}
});
```

Collection:

```
ShotsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Shot,
  sync: function(method, model, options) {
    var params = _.extend({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: model.url(),
        processData: false
    }, options);
    return $.ajax(params);
  },
  parse: function(response) {
    return response.shots;
  },
  url: function() {
    return "http://api.dribbble.com//shots?per_page=12/popular";
  }
});
```

View:

```
DribbleView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el : $('#dribble_container'),
  template : _.template($('#dribble_details').html()),

  initialize : function() {
    var self = this;
    self.collection = new ShotsList();
    self.collection.fetch({
        success: function(){
            self.render();
        }
    });
  },

  render : function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template( this.collection.get("image_url") ));
    return this;
  }
});

view1 = new DribbleView();
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're encountering is your collection doesn't have `image_url`.  The collection's shot models will each have `image_url`.

You can use an underscore function to just get an array of each shot's image_url:

```
this.collection.pluck("image_url")
```

However, this won't work within your template.  Your template will receive an array, but the template itself is trying to access image_url on an  object

Comment: What I have so far is what I cobbled together looking at other posts. I'm sure there is a smarter way to do what I'm trying to do. I'm just unfamiliar with the patterns and the way backbone does things.